# Let $f : M\to N$ be a submersion with $M$ compact and $N$ connected. The $f$ is surjective.

Tags: differential-topology

I have no idea how to do this. I tried think in, once $N$ is connected and locally path connected it has to be path connected, but, this does not help. Any hints, solutions, will be very appreciate...

Now I realized that $f(M)$ will be also compact... But, how to conclude the claim?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: The image set $f(M)$ will be compact, so closed. And the rank of $f$ will be $= \dim N$ for any $p\in M$, so $f(M)$ will be...

Comment: I am inclined to say that $f(M) = N$, but, where do I using connectedness?

Comment: If $N$ is connected then all the tangent spaces have the same dimension as $N$.

Comment: @user Hint 2: you need it to go from the hint to your conclusion that $f(M)=N$. Think about embedding a sphere into the disjoint union of two spheres.

Comment: @Sam now I see, thanks a lot. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @user43687, thank you! Nice example, I do appreciate!